# Notepad++ FTP Sync with server on connection

Tags: ftp, connection, notepad++, sync

Is it possible for notepad++ to automatically sync with a ftp server when you connect to it via etc. nppftp to get the files from the server; that you have set up a cache for on your local computer, when you do the connection; so you simply have updated files whenever you connect the server via NPPFTP.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issues? I am using NPPFTP to work at home an in the office on the same files. And I just realized that NPPDFP does not sync with the files upon opnening. Maybe it would be best to force closing of all windows when Notepad++ exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think notepad++ has a built-in mechanism for that. However you can use one of these software to the same end result depending on your remote file system.

[win-sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/)

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

They both can synchronize your file system in the background. So you can just work as if your files are local.